# How to get a child collection when the id of the parent isn't in the URL?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a `Book` and a `Chapter` collection. In a template called `book_list.html` there's an `each`  statement listing all the `book` items:

```
<!-- book_list.html -->

<template name="bookList">
  <div class="book-list">
    {{#each books}}
      {{> bookItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
```

In order to get the word count I created a helper in `book_item.js` which works by fetching all the `chapters` in the `book` and returning the sum of all of their words.

Everything was OK, until I decided to remove the `autopublish` package and use `publish` and `subscribe` instead. The problem now is that I don't know how to do get the ID of the current book in `book_list` since its ID is not present in the URL (`book_list` is the home page).

This is the code (minus the code for the word count):

```
//publications.js

Meteor.publish("books", function() {
  return Books.find({});
});

Meteor.publish("chapters", function(bookId) {
  return Chapters.find({
    bookId: bookId
  }, {
    sort: {
      position: 1
    }
  });
});

//route.js

Router.map(function() {
  this.route("bookList", {
    path: "/",
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe("books");
    },
    data: function() {
      return Books.find({});
    }
  });
});

//book_item.js

Template.bookItem.helpers({
  words: function() {
    var chapters = Chapters.find({
      bookId: this._id
    }).fetch();

    // code for the word counter
```

Comment: Tell me, where you using `words` helpers in the template ?

Comment: Inside the `{{#each}}` loop, you can get the id of the current book with `{{_id}}` in the template or `this._id` in the helpers.

Comment: @ajduke It's in `book_item.html` something like `<li>{{title}} {{words}}</li>`.

Comment: @user3557327 No, even though I use this._id the document is not being retrieved I think it's because it's not being `subscribed`.